# Dichotomous variables analysis

Tags: chi-squared-test

I am analyzing data from different dichotomous variables. When analyzing association between these variables, what is the most recommended method?

Comment: There exist dozens of measures of association between dichotomous or binary variables. Note that in some situations binary (= "ordinal dichotomuus": present vs absent) should be treated differently than "nominal dichotomous" (eg male vs female)

Comment: @ttnphns: Could you please elaborate a little on ordinal dichotomous vs nominal dichotomous ? - sounds interesting.

Comment: Agree with @ttnphns. I have mainly ordinal dichotomous in my study vs. some categorical variables. How can I find associations between dichotomous and categorical variables?

Comment: @Scortchi, at first glance all dichotomous attributes are formally the same. But if you compare logic behind some association indices, for example, Jaccard coefficient vs Russel-Rao coefficient, the difference becomes apparent. "Attribute X present vs attribute X absent" isn't quite the same as "Attribute X present vs alternative attribute Y present".

Comment: @ttnphns: Thanks v. much! I'll read up on those, & post a question here if I still can't see it.

Comment: Of possible interest: [Cross tabulation of two categorical variables: recommended techniques](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/192/930). If you can't give us more details on the purpose of the analysis and how data were collected, this question is no more than a duplicate.